# ASP.NET string resource to lower case?

Tags: asp.net, localization, webforms, resx

I'm including a string resource in an ASPX:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Global, MyString %>"/>
```

Let's say the value of `MyString` is "Home". How can I convert that to lower case ("home") in the resource tag? E.g., I don't want to have to store both upper/title and lower case variants of the string in the resource file.

I realize I could do this normally (outside a control) like this:

```
<%= Resources.Global.MyString.ToLower() %>
```

But that doesn't help when I have to use a resource for some property of a control. I was hoping to be able to do something simple such as:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ (Resources:Global, MyString).ToLower() %>"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up building my own `ExpressionBuilder` which uses the built-in `ResourceExpressionBuilder` to get the underlying resource value and then convert it to lower case:

**Convert the Base Expression to a Lower-case String**

```
public class ResourceLowerCase : ResourceExpressionBuilder
{
    public override CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry, object parsedData, ExpressionBuilderContext context)
    {
        CodeExpression getResourceExpression = base.GetCodeExpression(entry, parsedData, context);
        CodeMethodInvokeExpression toStringExpression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(getResourceExpression, "ToString");
        CodeMethodInvokeExpression toLowerExpression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(toStringExpression, "ToLower");

        return toLowerExpression;
    }
}
```

**Register the Expression Builder**

```
<system.web>
    <expressionBuilders>
        <add expressionPrefix="ResourceLowerCase" type="My.Project.Compilation.ResourceLowerCase"/>
    </expressionBuilders>
</compilation>
```

**Invoke the Expression Builder**

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ ResourceLowerCase:Global, MyString %>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Code:
GetGlobaloResources("MyString").ToString().ToLower() %>"/>
```

Just pseudo code.

Update:
http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

Just use the CodeExpressionBuilder from above link.

Comment: It doesn't look like you can use any "code" inside the `<%$ %>` block: `The expression '<%$ Resources.Global.MyString.ToLower() %>' is invalid. Expressions use the syntax <%$ prefix:value %>`